# stacks in ROS hydro; roswtf missing /opt/ros/hydro/stacks

Tags: ros, stack, ros-hydro, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Observations:**

- roswtf gives me an error stating that `Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH point to an existing directory`; the missing one is `/opt/ros/hydro/stacks`;
- I believe that the `/opt/ros/hydro/stacks` item in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable comes from the `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` script;
- if I understand it correctly, [there are no stacks in ROS hydro](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview);
- there already is [an answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/96496/roswtf-errors-after-following-install-and-configuration-of-ros-tutorial/?answer=97766#post-id-97766) proposing to simply create the missing stacks directory;
- There is [a document](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html) that states that the `/opt/ros/hydro/stacks` directory is there for backwards compatibility with rosmake packages

**Question:**

Is there a bug in `/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` or should have been the `/opt/ros/hydro/stacks` created during installation? Where to report that bug/how to find out what package is responsible for creation of such a directory?

**The environment:**

I am running ROS hydro on top of Ubuntu 12.04.3. My system contains an installation of ROS groovy too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115376/stacks-in-ros-hydro;-roswtf-missing-/opt/ros/hydro/stacks/) by [Filip Jareš](https://answers.ros.org/users/3478/filip-jare%C5%A1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since users are still able to build dry packages and stacks the `stacks` folder under `/opt/ros/hydro` has not been removed. A user could still "install" dry stacks there manually.

The actual error message of `roswtf` will go away with the next release of it. It has been already changed in the source repository (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/935266512550e65502d47163b0ca0f4a8c4e3379). So you can just ignore the message until then.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1